# What is this こうした家内産業?

Tags: grammar

For full context, see here:
https://www.docdroid.net/hK45eJm/img-20170916-0001-new.pdf

The following sentence is taken from line 10:

> この[辺]{あた}りは農作物ができないため、江戸時代にこうした家内産業が発展した。

"Because in this area crops weren't possible, in the edo area ???? wife industry made growth/grew."

"wife industry" sounds pretty odd, I guess it is meant that the wife does work at home? However, what does this have to do with crops???

Answer (score 3):

The English term for 家内産業 is "cottage industry."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Putting-out_system

Does it make sense now?

Comment: I agree with @mamster. Maybe you can see around more this term instead: 家内工業{かないこうぎょう}

Answer (score 0):

I think こうした just means houses *like these*.

In the sentences prior it talks about how they specifically built it to make summer feel cool and winter feel warm, and also how life inside involved raising silk worms and creating the stuff for gunpowder.

So, it appears that those "industries" thrived because the inhabitants did not spend their time on crops. Regarding 家内, I think this word is a bit old. Maybe it implies wife since typically they had to stay at home...